# Converting from score to grade

Tags: javascript

I am struggling all day with this one. I need to call function scoreGrade in order to get grade as a number. Could you tell me what do I need to correct? I tried with this code, but I can't figure out the rest. :/

```
function endQuiz() {
var grade = scoreGrade();

if (myAnswers[(lengthofobject-1)] {
    var output = "<div class='output'>Резултат<br>";
    var questionResult = "NA";
    //console.log('Quiz Over');
    for (var i = 0; i < myAnswers.length; i++ || "ten-countdown"<1)) {
        if (data.quizcontent[i].correct == myAnswers[i]) {
            questionResult = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
            correct++;
        } else {
            questionResult = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        }
        output = output + '<p>Питање ' + (i + 1) + ' ' + questionResult + '</p> ';
    }

    var grade = scoreGrade(correct, lengthofobject)
    document.getElementById("ocena").innerHTML = grade;

    function scoreGrade(){
        let score = (correct / lengthofobject) * 100;
        let grade;

        if (score>=85)  {grade ='5'}
        else if (score>=70) {grade ='4'}
        else if (score>=55) {grade ='3'}
        else if (score>=40) {grade ='2'}
        else {grade ='1'}

        return grade;
    }
    clearInterval(endTime);
    output = output + '<p>Имате ' + correct + ' од ' + lengthofobject + ' тачних одговора.</p></div> ';
    document.getElementById("quizContent").innerHTML = output;
} else {
    //console.log('not answered');
}
```

Comment: you don't appear to be calling the `scoreGrade` function anywhere, and even if you did you can't include HTML syntax directly in JavaScript like you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is inside the `scoreGrade` function, which does not return anything. Let's modify it like so:

```
function scoreGrade(correct, questions.length) { 

    let score = (correct/questions.length) * 100;

    if (score>=85) { return (<h4>Vaša ocena je 5.</h4>); }
    else if (score>=70) { return (<h4>Vaša ocena je 4.</h4>); }
    else if (score>=55) { return (<h4>Vaša ocena je 3.</h4>); }
    else if (score>=40) { return (<h4>Vaša ocena je 2.</h4>); }
    else { return (<h4>Vaša ocena je 1.</h4>); }
}
```

This function would work, but not with vanilla js. Returning html in js is a jsx practice. If you're not using jsx consider just returning the grade value as a string or integer.

Comment: Hi, I tried to correct it, but I can't get through it... Could you help me with the new code? Thank you for your time, really appreciate it!